# Is it Safe to use ReaderWriterLockSlim in an async method

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Since the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` class uses Thread ID to see who owns the lock is it safe to use with async methods where there is no guarantee that all the method will be executed on the same thread.

For example.

```
    System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim readerwriterlock = new System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    private async Task Test()
    {
        readerwriterlock.EnterWriteLock();
        await Task.Yield(); //do work that could yield the task
        readerwriterlock.ExitWriteLock(); //potentailly exit the lock on a different thread
    }
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Is it Safe to use ReaderWriterLockSlim in an async method

Yes and no.  It can be safe to use this in an async method, but it is likely not safe to use it in an async method where you enter and exit the lock spanning an `await`.

In this case, no, this is not necessarily safe.

[ExitWriteLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.exitwritelock.aspx) must be called from the same thread that called `EnterWriteLock`.  Otherwise, it throws a `SynchronizationLockException`.  From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.exitwritelock.aspx), this exception is thrown when:

> The current thread has not entered the lock in write mode.

The only time this would be safe is if this was used in an async method which was always in an environment where there was a current `SynchronizationContext` in place which will move things back to the same thread (ie: Windows Forms, WPF, etc), and wasn't used by a nested async call where a "parent" up the call chain setup a Task with `ConfigureAwait(false)` (which would prevent the `Task` from capturing the synchronization context).  If you are in that specific scenario, you'd know the thread would be maintained, as the `await` call would marshal you back onto the calling context.

Comment: I'm reading this question and the two answers, yours and Stephen Cleary contradict each other. I'm confused. I understand why in WPF for example, the lock is not an issue because it's same thread which got the lock in the first place, but Stephen says, despite being same thread, ReaderWriterLockSlim is always a problem with async, no matter the environment

Comment: @DonBox Well, it's not "always" a problem - it can work, but it's dangerous. I suggest that, as well. As he mentioned, with the same context, you can still get reentrancy problems which will cause a deadlock - if you know your routine will never get called >1 time reentrantly, it should work, but that's a big "if"

Comment: Even with a synchronization context, you could run into an issue of invalid recursion, where your synchronization thread gets a read lock, awaits, and then a different task running on the synchronization thread tries to get a write lock.  This is invalid recursion for `ReaderWriterLockSlim` and will throw.

Answer (score 29):

No. Thread-affine coordination primitives should not be used as in your example.

You correctly identified the problem where a different thread can be used to resume after the `await`. There is another issue due to the the way `async` methods return early: the caller is not aware that the lock is held.

`ReaderWriterLockSlim` by default is a non-recursive lock, so if another `async` method attempts to take the same lock, you'll get a deadlock. Even if you make the lock recursive, you'll still end up with a problem: arbitrary end-user code should never be called while holding a lock, and that's essentially what you're doing when you use an `await`.

The [`SemaphoreSlim` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.aspx) is `async`-aware (via its `WaitAsync` method), and Stephen Toub has a [series of `async` coordination primitives](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10267069.aspx) also available in my [AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncReaderWriterLock).

Comment: Can you please give a concrete example for the 3rd paragraph 
"so if another async method attempts to take the same lock, you'll get a deadlock". 
I don't understand how the deadlock could appear in an environment like WPF for example.

Comment: @DonBox: Just have a button click that takes a writer lock and then does `await Task.Delay(10000);` and click it again before 10 seconds elapse.