# Lock resource for one type of consumer

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, uwp, .net-core

I have single resource (StorageFolder) and which I access in operations:

- AddFileAsync
- ReadFileAsync
- DeleteFolderAsync

I use `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` class to lock the resource, so it won't be accessed by multiple operations at the same time.

What .net class should I use instead of `SemaphoreSlim` so that I will be able to call multiple `AddFileAsync`. and `ReadFileAsync` concurently, but I won't be able to call `AddFileAsync`(resp `ReadFolderAsync`) and `DeleteFolderAsync` concurently.

In other words, I want to prevent deleting folder while other thread is reading/wrinting to it.

current code (try/finally blocks ommited):

```
_sempaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

async Task AddFileAsync(){
   await _sempaphore.WaitAsync();
   await _storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(....)
   _sempaphore.Release();
}

async Task DeleteFolderAsync(){
   await _sempaphore.WaitAsync();
   await _storageFolder.DeleteAsync()
   _sempaphore.Release();
}
```

Comment: Why not depend on the built-in OS filesystem locks?

Comment: Filesystem locks would throw exception, wouldn't they?

Comment: Yes, they would throw.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: First, I'd say a single exclusive lock on the entire filesystem would be best. Most drives are spinning platters, so the hardware can only do one thing at a time anyway. If that won't work for you, then a hierarchy of exclusive locks would be my next choice. But if you truly have heavily nested code *with lots of read concurrency*, then you can use nested asynchronous reader/writer locks. Those are some nasty lock hierarchies, though. It just seems like this is a solution for something that isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx

ReaderWriterLockSlim allows multiple readers and one writer.

Edit: now that I read the question more carefully I noticed the async; you can't use ReaderWriterLockSlim if you use async. See [ReaderWriterLockSlim and async\await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659387/readerwriterlockslim-and-async-await) for an alternative.

Comment: I've used `Nito.AsyncEx` nuget package at the end from the second link.