# How do I use RWLock to implement many readers-one writers scenario right?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, rwlock

I'm trying to write a method which process some messages. They can be read or write  messages. Parallel reads are permitted, but when `write` lock is aquired all subsequent read lock should wait until write lock is released. So I thught `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is what I need. But when I'm trying to implement simple application to see if it works as expected I get `Recursive read lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode` exception.

Here is my example to show how it's intended to work:

```cs
ReaderWriterLockSlim distributionLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

async Task ExecuteReadLockTaskAsync(Func<Task> taskFunc)
{
    distributionLock.EnterReadLock();
    try
    {
        await taskFunc();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (distributionLock.IsReadLockHeld)
        {
            distributionLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }
}

async Task ExecuteWriteLockTaskAsync(Func<Task> taskFunc)
{
    distributionLock.EnterWriteLock();
    try
    {
        await taskFunc();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (distributionLock.IsWriteLockHeld)
        {
            distributionLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}

Task ProcessAsync(bool flag)
{
    switch (flag)
    {
        case false:
            return ExecuteReadLockTaskAsync(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Readonly task start");
                return Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Readonly task done"));
            });
        case true:
            return ExecuteWriteLockTaskAsync(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Write task start");
                return Task.Delay(3000).ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Write task done"));
            });
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unknown message typex");
    }
}

var tasks=  new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(ProcessAsync(false));
}
tasks.Add(ProcessAsync(true));

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(ProcessAsync(false));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Expected result: 100 lines of `Readonly task start`, one line of `Write task start`, then 100 lines of `Readonly task done`, then one line of `Write task done`, then the rest of program prints.

Actual result:

```
Readonly task start
Readonly task done

LockRecursionException4
Recursive read lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode.
```

I don't get where recursion appears here. I'm just calling one function, without any kind of recursion. I read articles but I don't see how it works here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it Safe to use ReaderWriterLockSlim in an async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882710/is-it-safe-to-use-readerwriterlockslim-in-an-async-method). (The answer is "no".)

Comment: My error is different. Howerver, this link is useful, thanks.

Comment: Different error, but same root cause -- the lock won't be released if the `await` ends up on a different thread from when it started (as it doesn't think it's holding the lock), and when the task eventually does run on a thread that is still holding the lock, you'll get this error.

Comment: Yes, I get it. Then it's actually a duplicate. But I don't see any answer how can I emulate then to make it work. Maybe I should change question subject?

Comment: Stephen Cleary's answer links to his [AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) library, which has an `AsyncReaderWriterLock`.

Comment: Yeah, I used it and it works as expected. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend **not** using RWLs of any kind unless performance testing shows it would be useful. RWLs are only appropriate when there is a split between readers and writers **and** writers are rare **and** there's a lot of contention between readers. Otherwise, just use a plain lock (`SemaphoreSlim` in the async case). In particular, if an app does not have a lot of lock contention, then it doesn't need a RWL.

Comment: @StephenCleary I have a lot of requests that should be processed in parallel unless there are some other requests, then these requests should wait until the second ones proceed. Why should I rewrite these primitives myself instead of just taking existing ones? Is there really big problems with entering in read locks?

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy: Jumping to RWL is a common problem, and it often is not a good match to the problem. E.g., what you're trying to do is *prioritize work,* not *manage exclusive access.* What happens next month when you need to add another priority level? And a RWL wouldn't allow the second requests to operate in parallel.

Comment: No, I want exlusive access, not some kind of priority. It's actually some sort of caching data and updating it. I won't have a "third" option here. I only can get data or update it, nothing more.